# What could cause these weird errors: undefined local variable or method `mutations_from_database' (and similar)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, amazon-ecs

Recently we started to see weird errors coming from our Ruby-on-Rails application. Most of them have the message `undefined local variable or method 'mutations_from_database'`, but sometimes also referring to other undefined method names:

`undefined method 'partial_writes?'`

`undefined method 'assign_attributes'`

These methods are mostly Rails-internal and not part of our application, so they should be defined. Moreover, the application works in 98% of the time without these errors, but sometimes they appear for certain instances of our application continuously until we re-deploy or re-launch the application.
Somehow it seems that not all Rails methods were initialized?!

The application itself is deployed on AWS ECS in a docker container. During deployment the application is copied into the container (build time).

Currently, we am running out of ideas. Any thoughts or hints?

Could it have something to do with lack of available memory? But if memory is exceeded, ECS would kill these instances immediately instead of leaving them running not fully initialized. Limited CPU resources should also not be a problem, because that would make the initialization just slow and not incomplete, right?

**Update:** Some more context: When checking the `ancestors` of the failing class, then it seems that some of the `ActiveModel` modules, e.g. `AttributeAssignment`, are missing. How could that happen?

Comment: You probably need to add a little more details. One I just thought of: how is your application code made available to the container: copy in container filesystem at build time ? mount from an external volume ? Which type of volume ? ...

Comment: During deployment the application is copied into the container (build time).

Comment: Sounds like a call to an ActiveRecord model is being resolved as a non-AR constant. I'd look into the specific cases and see whether any duplicate constant names are being used. Rails loading can be quite finicky.

Comment: All affected classes inherit from `ApplicationRecord`, which itself inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`. Nothing too fancy here. And I don't see any conflicting constant names.

Comment: Some more context: When checking the `ancestors` of the failing class, then it seems that some of the `ActiveModel` modules, e.g. `AttributeAssignment`, are missing. How could that happen?